# Como filtro dados de acordo com parte dos caracteres de uma variável?

Tags: r

Como posso, por exemplo, listar somente as observações que contém na variável Nome, a palavra Silva?

```
Nome                Nota
    João Silva      9
   Pedro Souza      8
     Ana Silva      6
Isabela Cabral      10
  Paulo Santos      5
```

Gostaria que imprimisse somente uma tabela desta maneira:

```
Nome                Nota
    João Silva      9
     Ana Silva      6
```

Sou novo aqui, me desculpem pela forma da apresentação do problema. Grato desde já!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suponha que o seu conjunto de dados se chama `dados`:

```
dados <- data.frame(Nome=c("João Silva", "Pedro Souza", "Ana Silva",
  "Isabela Cabral", "Paulo Santos"), Nota=c(9, 8, 6, 10, 5))
```

Utilize a função `grep` para encontrar quais linhas possuem a palavra que te interessa. No caso, as linhas 1 e 3:

```
grep("Silva", dados$Nome)
[1] 1 3
```

Selecione apenas estas linhas no conjunto de dados original e está resolvido o seu problema:

```
dados[grep("Silva", dados$Nome), ]
        Nome Nota
1 João Silva    9
3  Ana Silva    6
```

Answer (score 7):

Usando a resposta do Marcus, quero só chamar a atenção para uma coisa que muitas vezes passa despercebida a utilizadores "novos" do `R`, que é a variável dados$Nome ser de classe `factor`. Isto tem importância no resultado final, depois de eliminados os valores que interessam os níveis (`levels`) da variável continuam lá. Veja-se com código:

```
dados2 <- dados[grep("Silva", dados$Nome), ]
str(dados2)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Nome: Factor w/ 5 levels "Ana Silva","Isabela Cabral",..: 3 1
 $ Nota: num  9 6

dados2$Nome
[1] João Silva Ana Silva 
Levels: Ana Silva Isabela Cabral João Silva Paulo Santos Pedro Souza
```

Se quiser eliminar estes níveis pode-se utilizar a função `droplevels`.

```
dados2$Nome <- droplevels(dados2$Nome)
dados2$Nome
[1] João Silva Ana Silva 
Levels: Ana Silva João Silva
```

A outra solução será começar logo por, ao criar a `data.frame` `dados`, usar o argumento `stringsAsFactors`.

```
dados <- data.frame(Nome=c("João Silva", "Pedro Souza", "Ana Silva",
  "Isabela Cabral", "Paulo Santos"), Nota=c(9, 8, 6, 10, 5),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   ## Aqui, por defeito é TRUE
```

Depois é só usar a solução do Marcus.

Answer (score 1):

Usando o df criado pelo @Marcos, você também pode trabalhar com tidyverse, sem a dificuldade apresentada pelo @Rui:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(stringr)
    dados <- tibble(Nome=c("João Silva", "Pedro Souza", "Ana Silva",
                           "Isabela Cabral", "Paulo Santos"),
                    Nota=c(9, 8, 6, 10, 5)) %>% 

      .[str_which(.$Nome,"Silva"),]
```